# My training results graph is blank. How can I fix that?

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I'm working on a text classification project. I use DistilBert model.

This is how my compute metrics function is:

```
train_loss_list = []
val_loss_list = []
val_acc_list = []

def compute_metrics(pred):
   labels = pred.label_ids
   preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
   probs = softmax(pred.predictions, axis=-1)
   pos_probs = probs[:, 1]

  if hasattr(pred, 'loss'):
     train_loss_list.append(pred.loss.item())
  if hasattr(pred, 'eval_loss'):
     val_loss_list.append(pred.eval_loss.item())

  pos_probs_list = pos_probs.tolist()

  acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
  val_acc_list.append(acc)

  return {
     'accuracy': acc,
     'probs': pos_probs_list,
     'loss': pred.loss.item() if hasattr(pred, 'loss') else None
}
```

My training args:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
   output_dir='results',
   num_train_epochs=3,
   per_device_train_batch_size=16,
   per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
   logging_dir='logs',
   logging_steps=200,
   save_steps=200,
   evaluation_strategy="epoch")
```

And i defined compute metrics in trainer too:

```
trainer = Trainer(
model=model,                        
args=training_args,               
train_dataset=train_dataset,         
eval_dataset=valid_dataset,          
compute_metrics=compute_metrics)
```

But my training results graph is empty. I printed train_loss_list, val_loss_list, and val_acc_list lengths and the output was 0 0 4. So lists are not getting updated during training. Why is this happening?